# Why was this question reopened when there were already many duplicates explaining the problem which could be used to solve OP's problem?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently closed [Why does my code work without inheritance but not with inheritance in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331853/why-does-my-code-work-without-inheritance-but-not-with-inheritance-in-c) as it has plenty of duplicates (around 6) of which I can found in the first search on Google.

But then some user reopened this question without giving any reason. My question was this question incorrectly reopened and was this a misuse of power since

a) the reopening reason was not given by the user who reopened it

b) there already exist many duplicates for the question, many of which can be found on [the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76331853/timeline).

---

All of those duplicates (the answers there really) describe the problem and can be used to solve the OP's problem. So I think that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331853/why-does-my-code-work-without-inheritance-but-not-with-inheritance-in-c) was incorrectly reopened.

Comment: Regarding a), users are not required to give reasons for reopening questions, at least on the main site. You could ping the user to ask for their reason, but they still don't have to give one.

Comment: @cigien Yup, I am aware of that. Though I think when I posted a comment saying *"There was no reason to reopen this question as all the duplicates explain the problem and can be used to solve OP's problem."*, the person who closed the question was notified even though I did not explicitly mention/tagged their name. I noticed this ping behavior(without any name tags) for some questions that I close/reopen and then some person comment on that post.

Comment: No, I don't think they would be notified of that comment unless they were following the post. If there were no comments by other users on the post, then maybe the sole closer would get notified, but that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: It appears the question was deleted within the last hour.

Comment: This question was removed from Stack Overflow, how could we possibly answer your question? However, the fact that it was deleted probably means you were correct to begin with.

Comment: Because the answerer (and user who reopened) felt that the op had a mistake that wasn't spelled out word for word in the other answers on existing questions. *"While many of the duplicates say that the parent class constructor needs to be "called" in the constructor initializer list, few answers mention this specific issue: That the OP need to also get the arguments needed to pass to the parent class constructor. Examples might show it, but it's not explicitly spelled out."*

Comment: @KevinB That looks like spoon feeding. OP should be able to figure out the problem by looking at the answers given in the dupe.

Comment: @Jason ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ i never suggested i agree with them.

Comment: While I’m happy that garbage gets taken out, and removed from the site, it’s really annoying to be systematically discriminated in every single Meta discussion about these posts. I don’t have 10k+ reputation, which results in an effective ban from viewing what’s going on. I know I can ask some users to provide screenshots, but that’s suboptimal, noisy, annoying, and incomplete.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship there's a poorly agreed rule somewhere that posts discussed in meta should not be deleted. But to assume that the delete voters actually have seen this question is quite the stretch.

Comment: @Lino If the delete voters are active in chat, they probably have. But I’m not blaming them too much. Garbage is garbage. It’s the SE system that’s mainly at fault.

Comment: @Lino I think it's better to offer screenshots on Meta to the sub-10k users. Talking about curation shouldn't interfere with actual curation.

Answer (score 2):

The only trace of reasoning I can find is from a comment left by the answer author:

> While many of the duplicates say that the parent class constructor needs to be "called" in the constructor initializer list, few answers mention this specific issue: That the OP need to also get the arguments needed to pass to the parent class constructor. Examples might show it, but it's not explicitly spelled out.

This is a reason to *improve the existing Q&A* to make that clearer - since everyone who needs to use a base class' initializer list will need to understand that the *values* for that list need to *come from somewhere*.

Instead of closing every such question with multiple (up to 5) arbitrarily selected prior duplicates, the C++ tag community is supposed to examine existing versions of the question, select a *canonical* version of the question, improve that question as much as possible (with edits to the question and answers, and possibly also by adding a comprehensive, authoritative answer), and then *dupehammer everything else to that*.

A searchable Q&A library works when searching in substantively the same way reliably leads you to the same place, and when that place is the best available option.

Regarding comments here:

> That looks like spoon feeding. OP should be able to figure out the problem by looking at the answers given in the dupe.

For questions that are liable to be asked most commonly by novices, we **should** spoon-feed, as much as possible. This is the best way to make the question useful to the people most interested in it, and also the best way to *defeat resistance to dupe closures*.

Obviously we can't tailor the code preemptively to each new person's exact requirements, and we can't do anything about e.g. someone who doesn't understand the idea of changing variable names in an example to match the context where it will actually be used. However, we *can* anticipate common failure modes (such as defining a child constructor that doesn't take in information sufficient for constructing the base) and handle them explicitly in answers: by discussion ("When a subclass instance is constructed, a base instance also needs to be - so ensure that the information provided to the subclass constructor is adequate for figuring out base class constructor parameters"), by positive example (show code complex enough to highlight e.g. cases where base class constructor parameters are synthesized, rather than directly forwarded), and by negative example ("Here are some things people commonly try that don't work:").