# Why was this question reopened when there were already many duplicates that solves OP's problem?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I recently closed [Casting a void pointer to a 2D String array pointer (C/CPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387588/casting-a-void-pointer-to-a-2d-string-array-pointer-c-cpp) as it has plenty of duplicates which I found in the first search on Google.

But then some user reopened this question for the following [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387588/casting-a-void-pointer-to-a-2d-string-array-pointer-c-cpp#comment134698710_76387588):

> There is nothing in either of those so-called 'duplicates' about **casting** to a 2D array pointer.

Was this question incorrectly reopened and was this a misuse of power since **there already exist many duplicates that solve the problem**?

Comment: To be fair, user that reopened it gave a reason in comment right before reopening it.

Comment: @markalex Yes, but that reason is wrong imo since duplicates solve OP's problem. Additionally, the title of the question should be "forming a pointer to 2D array" as per the description of the content given in the question.

Comment: As a note, this *could* be written as a good question, but it comes across as some what accusatory and also contains incorrect information (that no reason was given).  Stating it's "misuse of power" without proof is setting quite a precedent, and it would be nice of you to offer proof it's misuse.

Comment: @ThomA The "without giving any reason" part was a copy/past mistake from my side. I had a template save for these type of questions and I made a mistake proofreading this question. That is, the "without giving any reason" part was there by mistake in this question. Edited that part out now.

Comment: Copy and pasting the same question makes me feel like this is the  a duplicate of a question you've previously asked, @Jason . Why are you not writing questions for the Question you want to ask..?

Comment: @rene Yes, as I explained in my previous comment, that "without giving any reason" was there in this question by my mistake. I forgot to remove that part out from my question when proofreading.

Comment: @ThomA I think there is nothing wrong with using a template to create a new question as long as the new question is about some problem that one might have. There can be millions of question like this describing different posts of the main site.

Comment: As an aside, giving a reason in commets has **never** been required for *any* types of votes; calling it misuse when someone doesn't make a comment after such a vote is outright incorrect.

Comment: @Jason: Now your question post includes the reasonings of the reopener.. but it doesn't contain **your reasonings** at all! And that really reduces value of your question, like absence of explanations reduces value of questions and answers on the main site.

Answer (score 14):

I'm going to use some context your other [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424831/why-was-this-question-reopened-when-there-were-already-many-duplicates-explainin) that you've freely admitted you've copied and pasted from to create this question.

Firstly it was opened because the user believed that the question was *not* a duplicate, it's *literally* as simple as that. No further context needs to be given; the user was a gold badge user and so they are trusted to know what is (and isn't) a duplicate.

<sub>There are instances where such users do abuse this privilege, however, this is often obvious when such users post answer (almost) **identical** to those on the prior duplicate and frequently reopen dupe questions, which is not the case here as far as I can tell.</sub>

Next your "misuse" claim. From your prior question, this seems to partly stem from your statement:

> the reopening reason was not given by the user who reopened it

This statement was *also* in this question, until multiple users called you out on it. Commenting on why you vote is ***never*** required, be that a close, down, up or reopen vote; stating that it is "misuse" of a vote when no comment is given, in my opinion, demonstrates a misunderstanding of the voting mechanics of your own.

As for that there are other duplicates, that is *your* opinion, and the other voter is entitled to theirs. Much like if a user votes up a question you think is bad, that is *not* misuse of votes. We are *all* entitled to use our votes as we see fit. *Misuse* of votes would be things like targetted votes on a user, or the scenario I offered in the subtext earlier; can you offer proof that the user in question is reopening *many* duplicate questions and then providing duplicate answers (answers that are near identical to answers on the duplicate questions)?

So no, this is not "misuse", it's an opinion of the user that the question is not a duplicate, and the user used their voting priviledge to denote that, by using the reopen feature; that's all that happened. No misuse, and the user was even kind enough to state their reason in the comments on the question being discussed. If you don't agree with that reason, well [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com) exists, where you can discuss it if you like, provided both parties are happy to do so.

Answer (score 11):

*Why was this question reopened ...*

You, a gold badge holder, closed the Q as a duplicate of what you believe are legitimate duplicates.

Another user, also a gold badge holder, disagreed and reopened it.

That's just the way the system works, get over it.  Leave it to others to vote.

OTOH, if by posting here on Meta you're hoping to invoke the Meta Effect, we'll, that's kinda disingenuous...

Comment: The only thing for which I posted this question was for that question to be closed again. The site exists for meta effect. There is nothing wrong in hoping for Meta effect.

Comment: @Jason Then find a post that explains how to cast a `void*` (a very common argument type in callbacks) to a pointer to an array (of any dimension) and I will hammer it closed myself.

Comment: Well, I'd call hoping to invoke the Meta Effect an abuse.

Comment: @Chris Meh. One more downvote on my original answer and I'll be eligible for a "Peer Pressure" badge. :)

Comment: @AdrianMole No need to spoonfeed every little detail. By reading the targets the OP can solve their problem.

Comment: @Jason Saying "*The only thing for which I posted this question was for that question to be closed again.*" and the fact that you have a template for such questions that you didn't even bother to proofread before posting, indicates that you've misunderstood what the meta site is for. Meta is intended for discussions, and you should at the minimum be willing to change your mind. Trying to invoke the "meta effect" for a result that you've already decided is the correct result is a misuse of meta in my opinion. Please stop posting such questions if you're not willing to have a proper discussion.

Comment: @cigien I don't see anything wrong with trying to invoke the meta effect or asking a question on meta.

Comment: @jason what's wrong with it is you are trying to raise an angry mob to enforce _your_ point of view.   Your view has no greater sway than anyone else`s

Comment: Well, unfortunately, @cigien, it looks like the meta effect has worked, and the OP achieved their goal; meaning that they are unlikely to learn their lesson.

Comment: @ThomA - Andnow it's reopeed. Maybe the user will learn the attempting to raise an angry mob cuts both ways.

Answer (score 10):

That question clearly ***is*** about casting – as the title and the quoted error message indicate. Although (as mentioned in the other answer and in the comments on my answer), there *may* be a more fundamental issue with the code and the OP's understanding of how to work with 2D arrays, casting to an array pointer is – in and of itself – a sufficiently tricky issue to warrant a stand-alone question, IMHO.

Comment: Although it does include a cast, the problem is with the used syntax of pointer to array.

Comment: @Jason is there a duplicate that specifically addresses the misunderstanding OP has? The duplicates you linked may answer the question (Note I am not an SME so cannot judge that) but something addressing it directly would probably be a better duplicate target

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Indeed - If someone finds a more reasonable duplicate, which does *really* answer the question, I would be happy to hammer it closed.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is possible that there are better duplicates available. I am saying that there are questions available(using which i closed the question) that can solve OP's problem and that once the OP reads the answers given in those duplicates, they will be able to solve their problem.